# How to combine SGD like SVM Kernel Approximation with Feature Selection on a Multiclass Dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to train a relatively large recordset. (200000 rows and 400 columns) in a pipeline. Only a weak notebook is available for the task.
This dataset has 15 independent classes and mixed categorical and numerical features. An SVM-like algorithm should be chosen.

I already tried to put some code together.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer,StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.kernel_approximation import RBFSampler
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

X, y= make_classification(n_samples=200000, n_features=130, n_informative=105,
                          n_redundant=25, n_classes=15, n_clusters_per_class=15)

#add some categorical columns
X [:,:2]= np.abs(X[:,:2]).astype(int)
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'F{i}' for i in range(X.shape[1])])
cols = X.columns.tolist()

y = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)

#%%Transformation  
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ('numerical', StandardScaler(), cols[2:]),
        ('categorical', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'), cols[:2])
        ])

#Sparse matrix
X = full_pipeline.fit_transform(X)

#set start
rbf = RBFSampler(gamma=0.1, random_state=42)
semi_svm = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", max_iter=50)

clf_pipe = Pipeline([
        ('rbf', rbf),
        ('svm', semi_svm)
        ])

cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5)

grid_search = RFECV(estimator=OneVsRestClassifier(clf_pipe), step=3, cv=cv, 
              scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)

grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

> ValueError: bad input shape (200000, 15)

How to handle the multiclass error in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worked for me:

```
...
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
...
rbf = RBFSampler(gamma=0.1, random_state=42)
semi_svm = OneVsOneClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", max_iter=5000))
selection = SelectKBest(k=1)

clf_pipe = Pipeline([
        ('rbf', rbf),
        ('features', selection ),
        ('svm', semi_svm)
        ])

cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5)

param_grid = dict(features__k=np.logspace(1,6, num=5, base=2).round().astype(int),
                  rbf__gamma = [0.1,1])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf_pipe, cv=cv, param_grid = param_grid, 
              scoring='f1', n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
```